# Failed executing gradlew using PHP exec through browser

Tags: php, curl, android-gradle-plugin, exec, gradlew

I want to run `gradlew` using PHP. What i have tried is using `exec(), shell_exec,` or `passthru`. I executed those commands inside a PHP script named *"build.php"*. I tried calling the script from a browser or curl and got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/6dibv5rcnnqlfbq9klf8imrndn/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
```

However when i called it from command line using `php build.php`, it worked very well. I

I need the `gradlew` command to be executed through user action from browser. My question: what might cause this error and how to get rid of it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have a folder named `.gradle` in `/var/www`
Create the folder and give `a+rw` permissions:

```
mkdir /var/www/.gradle
chmod a+rw /var/www/.gradle
```